# AJAX Request Empty From a DB Query

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sqlite

I'm making an AJAX request to grab information from a DB (already populated) in SQLite. Given the following code:

```
 response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"});
        var query = "SELECT * FROM Info";
        var data = {};
        var JSONf;
        db.all(query, function(err, rows) {
            JSONf = rows;
            data['info'] = JSONf;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            response.end(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        //response.end(data); // returns {}
        break;
```

when I do a

```
console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

in my main javascript file, it is just empty. Why isn't the information sending properly?

EDIT:

AJAX Function:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
if(xhr.readyState === 4){
  if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300)
  {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);


  }
}
};

xhr.open('GET', 'http://' + window.location.host + '/info', true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(err)` inside the callback?

Comment: @ppajer I get null

Comment: well... you haven't include the **ajax call**.. are we suppose to guess what you've written in there? note: you can use a 3-party lib (like jQuery) to test if the problem is within the ajax call itself or from your server

Comment: @ymz Edited the OP to include the call.

Comment: hhmmm...any chance that you get an error on your server? you didn't bother to check the **err** variable in your code... maybe the query itself failed....

Comment: check the browser network if the ajax call is actually happening? I prefer jQuery ajax call than vanilla.

Comment: If the query runs without error and the AJAX call completes successfully, I would guess the problem is with the `JSON.stringify`. It should return at minimum `{info: []}`. Try `console.log(rows)` before the `stringify`?

Comment: When I copied and pasted the first block of code to the top of my node server code, it worked. I honestly have no idea why it did.